# Are there any automated ways of getting PDF annotations into Word or LaTeX source code?

Tags: publications, peer-review, writing, latex, automation

With my previous two submissions to Elsevier journals, I have received reviews from 5 and 4 reviewers respectively. This results in a large number of comments that needs to be addressed. Some of the reviewers provide a PDF document with annotations that contain their comments and questions. Are there any automated or systematic ways of transferring these comments into my source code (LaTeX in my case but this question is just as applicable to MS Word) so that I can have a single view of all the comments?

Comment: Although I do agree with the close-voters, I think a simple solution is actually to just copy and paste, no?

Comment: @artificial_moonlet: It is certainly the best option I have been able to come up with. Alas, I am a hacker at heart and dream of automation. I'm just curious if anyone else has approached this problem differently.

Comment: Yeah, but: https://xkcd.com/1205/

Comment: If you are on linux, there is a tool called pdfannoteextractor which does what you ask for. But this is probably highly off-topic :)

Comment: Hi @nabla, thank you very much. I'll check it out. I think the challenge is to get the annotations into the source code after extracting the annotations.

Comment: @artificial_moonlet I agree (and also enjoy xkcd), I was hoping someone else did the legwork, allowing me to be on the right side of the chart.